# Why can't my Perl script differentiate between `0` and `" "`?

Tags: perl, replace, substr

Perl noob here - i have the following script

```
if(substr($pc, 3,1)!=" "){
       $newpc = substr($pc, 0, 4) . " " . substr($pc, 4);
}
```

It's designed to put a space in postcodes, for example `NN141NJ` becomes `NN14 1NJ`... however with postcodes such as `NN102DE` it doesn't do anything, does Perl recognize `" "` and `"0"` as the same? How can I go about perl not ignoring strings with `0` as the fourth letter?

Comment: I second that. Please use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: much better title @darch, it had been a long day - will keep in mind the error messages, this was literally the first time I've ever used perl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ne` instead of `!=`.  The latter is for numeric comparisons, in which both are `0` in your case.  See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)

Comment: cheers mate, I thought the syntax would be almost identical to PHP, knew it was too good to be true

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `!=` operator when you want to be using the `ne` (not-equal) operator. `!=` is a numeric-only compare, while `ne` is a string compare.

Answer (score 3):

It's because perl needs specification between string comparison and numeric comparison. You're using numeric comparison which would convert " " to a 0. Do this instead:

```
if(substr($pc, 3,1) ne " "){
       $newpc = substr($pc, 0, 4) . " " . substr($pc, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, this sort of string-bashing is usually done using regular expression operators.

So you might want to look at using `m//` and/or `s///`.

See "Regexp Quote-Like Operators" in the perlop documentation page, and also the whole perlretut documentation page.

Then again, if you are dealing with UK postcodes you might want to [search for "Postcode" on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Postcode) or look at [Geo::Postcode](https://metacpan.org/module/Geo%3a%3aPostcode)

Comment: Provides a good alternative, useful links as well, I'm already using `Geo::Postcode` in another part of this script